# Prove / Disprove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n(a_n+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n \ge 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is bounded, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n(a_n+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ diverges.

My attempt:

Since the series is bounded and $\ge 0$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges.

So there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \ge N$ we have $-1 \le a_n \le 1$.

So $\frac{1}{n(n-1)^\frac{1}{n}} \le \frac{1}{n(a_n+n)^\frac{1}{n}} \le \frac{1}{n\cdot (n+1)^\frac{1}{n}} \le \frac{1}{n \sqrt[n] n}$

From here I don't know what should I do next.

Any help will be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: Wait why do you know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges? The sequence defined as $a_n = 1$ for each $n$ is bounded and has $a_n\geq 0$ but the sum clearly does not converge.

Comment: @IskyMathews you are absolutely right! It simply bounded between 2 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{n\sqrt[n]{a_n+n}}}{\frac1n}=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n+n}}=1,$$since $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded and for each $k\in\Bbb N$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+k}=1$. So, since the harmonic series diverges, so does your series.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! :)